# My producer-consumer example won't work, but throws no errors

Tags: ruby

## THE INTENT

Each user has many albums; each album has many images. The class is instantiated with a user's name, and will download every one of their images. An image is represented as a hash with `:url`, `:title` and `:index` keys (index meaning image #1, #2, #3 etc in the album).

The producer will get a list of all albums, open album #1, push all images onto the queue, open album #2, push all images onto the queue, etc. Meanwhile the consumer looks at the queue, downloads an image, looks at the queue again, etc.

At the end of its work, the producer adds the symbol `:KILL` to the queue. The consumer checks for this symbol on every `pop` and if it sees it, it exits.

The object is described:

- `@queue = Queue.new`
- `@username`: a string
- `@threads`: an array of five threads, one producer and four consumers
- `#download`: saves an image object to a file in the user's folder
- `#albums_of_user`: takes nothing, returns an array of hashes, each representing an album belonging to the user, with the `:url` and `:title` properties
- `#images_in_album`: takes one of the above album hashes, returns an array of hashes representing images within the album, ready to be passed to `#download`
- `#consumer` and `#producer`: return a new consumer or producer thread

At the end of the `initialize` call, `@threads.map(&:join)` is called, to ensure that all threads complete their work.

### THE PRODUCER

```
Thread.new {
  albums_of_user.each do |album|
    images_in_album(album).each.with_index(1) do |image, index|
      @queue << image
    end
  end
  @queue << :KILL
}
```

### THE CONSUMER

```
Thread.new {
  loop do
    image = @queue.pop
    Thread.exit if image == :KILL
    download(image)
  end
}
```

## THE PROBLEM

The producer works, the download function works, but the consumers never do anything. I would love it if someone could point out where I've messed up.

## THE CODE

http://pastebin.ca/3180196

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the consumers aren't doing anything? You are only pushing one :KILL onto the queue, so only one of the consumer threads will be killed, resulting in either the program never ending or an error. You may not be getting any printed output because of buffer caching, so you might want to $stdout.flush as you are killing the thread.

See http://pastebin.ca/3180306 for an example. (Note: this removed the actual downloads because I wanted it to run fast :o)